# Android RecyclerView how to setup click listener - casting class to interface

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to understand how to implement click handler in RecyclerView. This is a piece of code that does click handler successfully.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private RecyclerView mList;
private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter();

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked: " + position + ", index " + mList.indexOfChild(view) + "VIew: " + view.getClass(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

SimpleAdapter.java

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.GameTileHolder> {

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

This example uses so called "loose coupling" which by definition a class is cast to an interface. Why isn't there an explicit cast to AdapterView.OnItemClickListener for example:

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)this);
```

What if this class implements more than just AdapterView.OnItemClickListener but another interface? Would the above explicit cast then be necessary?

Comment: No, the explicit cast is not needed. You would only need to explicitly cast in thr case of downcasting, for example, from `Object` to `String`. So no, if it implemented other interfaces, it would not be any different (no casting would be necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a cast in this case, because `MainActivityFragment` is lower in the hierarchy than the interface, so at ***compile time*** it is known that it implements `OnItemClickListener`.

You only need a cast if you only know at ***runtime*** that it implements that interface, for instance if you have a variable `Fragment f` that holds an object instance that was instantiated as a `MainActivityFragment`.

It is not a problem if the class implements multiple interfaces, because that doesn't introduce any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast because the method accepts a `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, and your `MainActivityFragment` **is an** `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

When you say that a class/interface U extends or implements another class/interface T, then instances of U are also instances of T. The compiler will allow you to use a reference of type U wherever a reference of type T is accepted.

Imagine the alternative.

```
Human: A truck is an automobile.
Compiler: Cool.
Human: This method accepts an automobile and washes it.
Compiler: OK.
Human: Send this truck through that method.
Compiler: Whoa, there, Nelly! You didn't tell me *this* truck is an automobile!
```

> What if this class implements more than just AdapterView.OnItemClickListener but another interface? Would the above explicit cast then be necessary?

No. If your MainActivityFragment implemented other interfaces, it would also be an instance of those interfaces, and no cast would be necessary.

Comment: Why use inheritance when you can just use interfaces?

Comment: Because sometimes you want to inherit *implementation*, not just an API. Ideally, this will be from an abstract class, but sometimes it is useful to inherit from concrete classes as well.